# Como exibir um código HTML ASP em uma Label enviando pelo Code-Behind(C#) - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, webforms

Estou tendo um problema, eu fiz vários testes onde eu desejaria enviar diretamente de um método do C# um código em HTML para uma label, onde ela exibiria dinamicamente o código na tela. Porém quando eu mando ela não renderiza.

```
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void FillPage(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(string.Format(@"<asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat='server' OnClick='LinkButton1_Click'><asp:Table ID='tableProd' class='tableProduto' runat='server'>
       <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell RowSpan='2' Width='155px'><img src='images/categorias/bebida.png' /></asp:TableCell>             
           <asp:TableCell Width='550px'>Nome</asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell RowSpan='2'>Preço</asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>       
           <asp:TableCell Width='550px'><div class='divTexto'><p>Descrição</p></div></asp:TableCell>             
        </asp:TableRow>          
    </asp:Table>
    </asp:LinkButton> "));

        lblTexto.Text = sb.ToString();                      
    }
}
```

Mas quando o código que é enviado para a label com o formato  ele não renderiza na tela. Apenas quando é enviado dessa maneira:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void FillPage(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(string.Format(@"<asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat='server' OnClick='LinkButton1_Click'><table ID='tableProd' class='tableProduto' runat='server'>
       <tr>
           <td RowSpan='2' Width='155px'><img src='images/categorias/bebida.png' /></td>             
           <td Width='550px'>Nome</td>
           <td RowSpan='2'>Preço</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>       
           <asp:TableCell Width='550px'><div class='divTexto'><p>Descrição</p></div></td>             
        </tr>          
    </table>
    </asp:LinkButton> "));

        lblTexto.Text = sb.ToString();                      
    }
}
```

Nem o LinkButton funciona.

Como poderia corrigir esse erro? Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está confundindo alguns conceitos fundamentais do ASP.NET aqui.

Quando você declara uma tag `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" />`, essa tag é interpretada pela engine do ASP.NET e um Html equivalente é gerado para que a página seja renderizada. Nesse caso, o que você tem na página final, ou seja, aquilo que o navegador exibe é uma tag `<a>`.

Se você realmente precisa coloca um controle servidor nesse ponto do código, você teria que fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
public void FillPage(int size)
{        
    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
    link.ID = "LinkButton1";
    link.Click += LinkButton1_Click;
    link.CommandArgument = "MEU_ARGUMENTO"; // utilize essa propriedade se precisar passar algum parâmetro para o EventHandler

    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
    table.Attributes.Add("class", "tableProduto");

    HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell td1 = new HtmlTableCell();
    td1.RowSpan = 2;
    td1.Width ="155px";

    HtmlImage img = new HtmlImage();
    img.Src = "images/categorias/bebida.png";

    td1.Controls.Add(img);

    HtmlTableCell td2 = new HtmlTableCell();
    td2.Width = "550px";
    td2.InnerText = "Nome";

    HtmlTableCell td3 = new HtmlTableCell();
    td3.RowSpan = 2;
    td3.InnerText = "Preço";

    tr.Cells.Add(td1);
    tr.Cells.Add(td2);
    tr.Cells.Add(td3);

    HtmlTableRow tr2 = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell td2Row2 = new HtmlTableCell();
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "divTexto");

    HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    p.InnerText = "Descrição";

    div.Controls.Add(p);
    td2Row2.Controls.Add(div);
    tr2.Cells.Add(td2Row2);

    table.Rows.Add(tr);
    table.Rows.Add(tr2);

    link.Controls.Add(table);

    lblTexto.Controls.Add(link);
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // recupera argumento, caso tenha sido passado
      string argument = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
}
```

Tenha em mente que controles criados dinamicamente devem ser recriados a cada postback, senão serão perdidos.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!!!! Foi de imensa ajuda Marcus!

Comment: Leia mais sobre criação de controles dinâmicos em http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8114/Dynamically-Created-Controls-in-ASP-NET e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Marcus, eu só tenho mais uma dúvida, eu queria útilizar essas tabelas pra preencher com informações no banco de dados e assim torná-la clicavel para me enviar para outra página. Eu usaria um Foreach criando várias dessas tabelas,só que não estou conseguindo criar um Evento On_Click para cada linkButton, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Você realmente precisa que cada link faça uma ação diferente? Que ação seria essa?

Comment: Eu preciso do seguinte : Cada tabela será preenchida com as informações dos produtos, aí cada tabela teria um evento de clique onde chamaria um método e enviaria como argumento o "ID" desse produto, onde chamaria outra pagina e preencheria os espaços com informações desse produto. Logo pensei que seria viável fazer um método para cada link button, onde cada um enviaria um determinado parametro de seu produto

Comment: Você pode utilizar a propriedade `CommandArgument` do `LinkButton` para guardar o ID (`link.CommandArgument = idProduto.ToString();`). Depois, dentro do EventHandler, para recuperar o id, faria algo assim: `string idProduto = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;`. Editei a resposta para incluir essa solução.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado Marcus, mesmo, se não fosse você não sei o que seria de mim, estou desenvolvendo um projeto com pouco conhecimento sobre asp, pessoas como você com boa vontade que me motivam a continuar e estudar! Obrigado, e tudo de bom!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar!